# Magento 2 Arabic language character saperated in Invoice PDF

Tags: magento2.2, pdf, invoice-pdf, arabic

I have facing the issue with arabic character in invoice PDF. You can see attach screenshot for better understanding. I guess here is some font issue but not getting exact idea how to resolve this issue.

[image]

You can see arabic character but it's not arabic. If anyone know the issue please help me resolve the issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you get solution for this? I have the same issue.

Comment: I had purchased an extension which resolved using it.

Comment: @KartikAsodariya which extension you purchase? please mention link and details